# Is there a way to call a function in tkinter as soon as the Window is opened?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter, I hope you can help. I'm on a Windows machine.

Here is an example for what I mean:

```
from tkinter import *    
def test():
    print("Window opened!")
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "FOO BAR")
text.pack()
root.mainloop(execute function)
```

Comment: If you did `root.after(1, test)`, anywhere between the calls to `Tk()` and `mainloop()`, the function would be called immediately after the window became visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does what you want. It uses the universal widget [`after_idle()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method so won't call the function until after the window has been displayed.

```
from tkinter import *

def test():
    print("Window opened!")
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "FOO BAR")
text.pack()
root.after_idle(test)  # Call test() next time system is idle.
root.mainloop()
```